# What are the major vulnerabilities of Redhat + Apache?

Tags: security

I am searching for a host for a new commercial website. Among other things, I'd like to know what the various OS - Webserver combinations have in terms of vulnerabilities. What are the vulnerabilities of Redhat + Apache?

Comment: Or an anti-phishing how-to. It's hard to tell, isn't it? :)
I didn't know we were restricted to code questions only. If I have to do or not do anything special in my code to deal with a particular platform, I might think that's a "programming question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_20.html

Answer (score 2):

Poor system admins is the biggest in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest risk to any web application server is vulnerabilities in the web application its self. Linux Apache MySQL and PHP (LAMP) is a very secure platform. RedHat's Fedora core is very secure because it uses SELinux, this is somthing that does not exist for Windows.  However vulnerabilities such as SQL Injection and XSS can still result in your server getting hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of a difficult question to answer, the development life cycles are so active you're asking for something that's likely to have been solved already ( and if its been reported so that we know of it, the likelihood its fixed is really high )

What you need is a 0-day hack for them, and asking this list really wont get you those.

Answer (score 0):

Any system is only as strong as its weakest link.  Invariably that will not be the OS or the server software, it will be the end application you develop or install.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87393/what-are-the-major-vulnerabilities-of-windows-2003-iis), I could check out the [CERT Database](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/).